# How do you build for Android Target SDK 31 with Capacitor 2?

Tags: android, capacitor

I'm currently using Capacitor 2 in my app and cannot currently upgrade to 3 or 4 but Google Play is now requiring new apps (and updates starting in November 2022) to target Android SDK 31.

I updated my `variables.gradle` file to have `targetSdkVersion = 31` and my aab builds just fine but when I go to upload it to Google Play it throws an error and says:

> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set.

And it links to [the following page](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported).

I checked my app's `AndroidManifest.xml` and added the correct `android:exported="true"` attribute but Google Play is still throwing the same error.

According to Capacitor's GitHub Issues they have no plans to backport the Android SDK 31 fixes to Capacitor 2. How can I work around this until I can upgrade to Capacitor 3/4?

Comment: Just out of interest: Why can't you update? I am trying to solve those problems.

Answer (score 3):

After some digging I found the file that was causing me issues was located at:

`src-capacitor/node_modules/@capacitor/android/capacitor/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

NOTE: This might be in your root `node_modules` file instead. I'm using Quasar (v1).

If you are building locally you can just edit that file and change the following line from:

`<service android:name="com.getcapacitor.CapacitorFirebaseMessagingService" android:stopWithTask="false">`

to

`<service android:name="com.getcapacitor.CapacitorFirebaseMessagingService" android:stopWithTask="false" android:exported="true">`

If you are using a build server and/or want this change to be in your code then you can either write a script to edit that line at build time or use something like [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package).

For me this was the only change I needed to make to be able to submit my app to Google Play but if you use other other Capacitor plugins there is a chance they need to be updated similarly. Open your android project in Android Studio, navigate to your main `AndroidManifest.xml` (`app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`), and click on the "Merged Manifest" button at the bottom of the file window.

[image: Merged Manifest button]

This view will combine all the `AndroidManifest.xml` files that your project uses and it will throw an error if it finds one that needs the `android:exported="true/false"` added (so you can hunt those down and fix them as well, or update those dependencies if they've fixed it)